# Get top N rows per day in Hive - rank()

Tags: sql, hive, rank

I have this table, each row donating a sale:

```
 sale_date  salesman  sale_item_id
 20170102   JohnSmith       309
 20170102   JohnSmith       292
 20170103   AlexHam          93
```

I'm trying to get the top 20 salesmen per day and I came up with this:

```
SELECT sale_date, salesman, sale_count, row_num
FROM (
  SELECT sale_date, salesman,
         count(*) as sale_count,
         rank() over (partition by sale_date order by sale_count desc) as row_num
  from salesforce.sales_data
) T
WHERE sale_date between  '20170101' and '20170110'
 and row_num <= 20
```

But I get:

```
FAILED: SemanticException Failed to breakup Windowing invocations into Groups. At least 1 group must only depend on input columns. Also check for circular dependencies.
Underlying error: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.SemanticException: Line 5:35 Expression not in GROUP BY key 'sale_date'
```

I'm not sure at what point the grouping would take effect though. Can someone help? Tx!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing a `group by` in the subquery:

```
SELECT sale_date, salesman, sale_count, row_num
FROM (SELECT sale_date, salesman,
             count(*) as sale_count,
             rank() over (partition by sale_date order by count(*) desc) as row_num
      FROM salesforce.sales_data
      GROUP BY sale_date, salesman
     ) T
WHERE sale_date between '20170101' and '20170110' and row_num <= 20;
```

I think Hive will accept the column alias in the `order by`, `order by sale_count desc`.

Also note that you can get more or fewer than 20 rows if there are ties.  You might want `row_number()` if you need exactly 20 rows.

Comment: Thanks @Gordon - I'm now getting the same error, but with "Expression not in GROUP BY key 'sale_count'".  AFAIK aliases cannot be used in group clauses but for the heck of it, I added it to the group clause and got "Invalid table alias or column reference 'sale_count'"

Comment: @lake . . . You do if the ranking is on an aggregation.

Comment: I just see the salescount, mb

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT sale_date, salesman, sale_count, row_num from (
SELECT sale_date, salesman, sale_count,
 rank() over (partition by sale_date order by sale_count desc) as         row_num
from 
(
SELECT sale_date, salesman,
   count(*) over (partition by salesman) as sale_count
from  employee
) t1
) t2  where sale_date between  '20170101' and '20170110'
and row_num <= 20;
WHERE sale_date between  '20170101' and '20170110'
and row_num <= 20
```

edited and testest. Your problem is essentially that you are trying to use the count before calculate it for your over clause, if you calculate your count in a subquery  paritioning by salesman, it will solve the problem. You cannot do a group by in the sales query, if you do, you won't have access to the sale_date.