# How to get the first subscription for each user (given that subscription ids change every time it renews automatically)

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, hiveql, greatest-n-per-group

Okay so I am in a bit of a pickle here.
I have **user_id, subscription_id, plan, subscription_start_date, subscription_end_date**.
I am looking for all the different plans that each user has purchased and the corresponding subscription_ids with only one id per plan(the very first one). The caveat is that  subscription ids change every time a user renews a subscription. So lets say user A has only one subscription and has renewed it 3 times hence has 3 different subscription ids, and user B has 2 plans and has renewed it twice so they have 4 subscription ids.

I am looking for user A to have 1 sub_id and 1 plan and user B have 2 sub ids and 2 different plans

Here is my query so far

```
SELECT H.plan, H.user_id
FROM my_table H
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT user_id, plan, MIN(subscription_purchase_date) As first_sub_date
    FROM my_table
    GROUP BY user_id, plan) X
ON H.user_id= X.user_id AND H.subscription_purchase_date = X.first_sub
```

| user_id | subscription_id | start_date | end_date | plan |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 123 | 2021-01-01 | 9999-01-01 | Premium |
| B | 122 | 2021-02-03 | 9999-03-04 | Regular |
| A | 144 | 2021-02-01 | 9999-01-01 | Premium |
| A | 155 | 2021-03-01 | 9999-01-01 | Premium |
| B | 167 | 2021-03-03 | 9999-03-04 | Regular |
| B | 111 | 2020-05-18 | 2021-12-18 | Trial |
| B | 187 | 2020-06-18 | 2021-12-18 | Trial |

Desired outcome

| user_id | subscription_id | start_date | end_date | plan |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 123 | 2021-01-01 | 9999-01-01 | Premium |
| B | 122 | 2021-02-03 | 9999-03-04 | Regular |
| B | 111 | 2020-05-18 | 2021-12-18 | Trial |

Thanks so much and let me know if you need additional info
PS I am using Hive/Hadoop

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: just did, THANK YOU

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get top N rows per day in Hive - rank()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42377774/get-top-n-rows-per-day-in-hive-rank)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use row_number() and filter.

Demo with your data example:

```
with my_table as (--data example, use your table instead of this CTE            
select 'A' user_id, 123 subscription_id, '2021-01-01' start_date, '9999-01-01' end_date, 'Premium' plan union all
select 'B', 122, '2021-02-03', '9999-03-04', 'Regular' union all
select 'A', 144, '2021-02-01', '9999-01-01', 'Premium' union all
select 'A', 155, '2021-03-01', '9999-01-01', 'Premium' union all
select 'B', 167, '2021-03-03', '9999-03-04', 'Regular' union all
select 'B', 111, '2020-05-18', '2021-12-18', 'Trial' union all
select 'B', 187, '2020-06-18', '2021-12-18', 'Trial'
)

select user_id, subscription_id, start_date, end_date, plan
from 
(
select user_id, subscription_id, start_date, end_date, plan,
       --Row with min start_date will be assigned rn=1
       row_number() over(partition by user_id, plan order by start_date) rn
from my_table
)s where rn=1
```

Result:

```
user_id subscription_id start_date  end_date    plan
A       123             2021-01-01  9999-01-01  Premium
B       122             2021-02-03  9999-03-04  Regular
B       111             2020-05-18  2021-12-18  Trial
```